# Combining file names with file numbers using a batch script

Tags: batch-file, count

I'm trying to number the files in a specific folder. My aim is to output the alphabetic position and the name of the file. So for a folder with for example two files in it (*hello.txt* and *world.txt*) I want the script to output something like this:

```
File 1 is hello  
File 2 is world
```

This is my script:

```
@echo off
cls

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folder=c:\test
set count=0

for /r "%folder%" %%a in (*.*) do (
    set file_!count!=%%~na
    set /a count+=1
    call :SUB
    )

if !count!==0 goto :EOF 

goto :EOF

:SUB
echo File !count! is file_%count%
```

Here is the output:

```
File 1 is file_1
File 2 is file_2
```

As you can see the output of the file names doesn't match my expectations.

I experimented with different variants of the filename variable:

Variant 2:

```
%file_!count!%
```

Output 2:

```
File 1 is world
File 2 is world
```

Variant 3:

```
%file_count%
```

Output 3:

```
File 1 is
File 2 is
```

Do you spot my mistake?

Comment: `:SUB` - `echo File !count! is !file_%count%!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The :SUB code must be this one:

```
:SUB
echo File !count! is !file_%count%!
```

This is a different way to do the same thing:

```
@echo off
cls

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folder=c:\test

for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D /S "%folder%" ^| findstr /N "^"') do (
   set file_%%a=%%~nb
   echo File %%a is %%b
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Your variant of the :SUB code doesn't work either. With your code I get the following output: `File 1 is` `File 2 is` Do you have another idea? The second way works. For the exact output I want to achieve I changed the last two lines, though: `set file_%%a=%%b` `echo File %%a is %%~nb`

Comment: Ah! This is because you assign a file name _first_, and then _modify_ the `count` variable! You must exchange these lines: `set file_!count!=%%~na` and `set /a count+=1` so the value of `count` be the same in the assignation and in the subroutine!!!

Answer (score 0):

pass the variable name as a parameter to the called routine

```
 ...
 call :SUB !count! file_!count!
 ....


:SUB
echo echo File %1 is !%2!
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but also with this variant I don't achieve the desired result. The output I get with your code is: `File 1 is` `File 2 is`